What's the difference between two types
type FilterOut<T extends any[], F> = T extends [infer E, ...infer Rest]
  ? [F] extends [E]
    ? FilterOut<Rest, F>
    : [E, ...FilterOut<Rest, F>]
  : [];

type FilterOut2<T extends any[], F> = T extends [infer E, ...infer Rest]
  ? [E] extends [F]
    ? FilterOut2<Rest, F>
    : [E, ...FilterOut2<Rest, F>]
  : [];

type Test = FilterOut<["a", never], never>;
//Output []

type Test2 = FilterOut2<["a", never], never>;
//Output ["a"]


It's different Output
playground
I had lookup  typescript's document about conditional type , but not get the reason。
So, Why [E] extends [F] and [F] extends [E] do not have same effect in this case?

Why did you expect them to have the same result? ["a"] and [never] obviously are different types, and only one is assignable to the other.

thx,I found some info about the reason

Found what where? Is the problem solved, can we close the question?

yes,it is solved
